# Share reference for all view in HTML page using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am new in PHP programming but have some experience using .NET MVC 4.
In .NET, we can specify the HTML page which will act as main layout that share the references (e.g Bootstrap, CSSs, Javascripts etc.etc) which normally being called shared view "_Layout". In PHP, is this possible and if yes, how can I achieve that?

thanks a lot

example:
Below reference will be used for all views in the project if specified;

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" ></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: you'll need a PHP framework to achieve something like that - PHP by itself is not a framework so doesn't supply these kinds of things. There are a few PHP frameworks, I myself use CakePHP but I believe Zend and Symfony are quite popular ones too.

Comment: Im not sure i not sure if this is what you are after but there is the (include) statement in php -- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I have edited my question and <head> section will be called / shared among views. will **include** statement allow this?